# NFC occasionally stops working. Fixed by battery removal.

Tags: nfc

I have written an app utilising the NFC radio running on Android 4.4. The NFC radio stops working on 2 occasions :

1. After an APK update.
2. Occasionally at other times.

The NFC function is still turned on and the system says it is working.

Interestingly the only thing that seems to fix it is *taking the battery out 
*

Powering on/off doesn't work and neither does switching NFC function off then on.

It's very hard to even find where the bug is occurring but given that battery removal works, my question is :

What does battery removal do to an android system that powering off completely doesn't do. Does it wipe a cache or reset something?

Comment: What phone is this?  If the NFC antenna is embedded in the battery, then removal and re-insertion may just be reseating the connection.